# What's wrong with my solution to Project Euler's #2 in C++?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

This is the question:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... By considering the terms in
>   the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find
>   the sum of the even-valued terms.

When I run the program below it gives me

> **-1833689714**

Can someone kindly help me out with the code?

========================================================================

[image: **enter image description here**]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fibona (int k);
int first = 0 , second = 1 , fibo = 0, sum = 0;

int main()
{
cout << "Sum of even values less than 4000000 : " ;
fibona (4000000);
}



int fibona (int k)
{
for (int c = 0 ; c < k ; c++)
{

    if (c <= 1)
    {
        fibo = c;
    }
    else
    {
        fibo = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = fibo;
    }
    if (fibo % 2 == 0)
    {

        sum += fibo;

    }

}



cout << sum <<endl;

}
```

Comment: "the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million" is not the same thing as the first four million terms.

Comment: your function is not returning anything, why does this ever compile?

Comment: @EduardRostoyman I brought a cout << sum at the end

Comment: its a cout, not a return

Comment: @interjay Can you kindly elaborate on the difference. I am a little confused

Comment: Writing into a global variable????

Comment: For example, "The terms which do not exceed 10" would be "1,2,3,5,8". But "The first 10 terms" would be "1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89". See the difference?

Comment: @ar2015 I meant the difference between "the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million" and the first four million terms

Comment: @interjay Thanks! I now get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how much is `Fib(4000000)`?

Must be approximately

```
((1+Sqrt[5])/2)^4000000/Sqrt[5] = 1.627477... × 10^835950
```

There is no way to fit it in any variable type.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long fibona_even_sum (long k);

int main()
{
    const long N=4000000;
    cout << "Sum of even Fibonacci numbers: " <<endl;
    cout << fibona_even_sum(N) <<endl;
}

long fibona_even_sum(long N_max)
{
    long first = 0 , second = 1;
    long sum=0;

    while(true)
    {
        long first_copy=first;
        first=second;
        second+=first_copy;
        if(second>N_max)
            return sum;
        if(!(second%2))
            sum+=second;
    }
}
```

In the code above you can change all `long` to `int`. It works fine.